# How to prevent liferay from changing language automatically

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I have a problem with Liferay 7.1 changing language automatically. I have two languages polish(default) and english. The problem is when guest is opening page on portal with link with english url. Liferay automatically redirects him to polish version of url. I know that this is because of FriendlyURLServlet.
How to change this behavior? Are there any properties to turn off this redirect? Or the only option is to overwrite this class?

Comment: which is the default language and what url are you calling ? is this the localized polish version or the default version?

Comment: Default is polish. It is default version of url. I'm calling url /individuals and being redirected to polish version /klienci-indywidualni.

Comment: so seems like, you call a default url but would like to see the English version ? what about taking the English one ? something like web/en/individuals

Comment: I am facing the same issue with 7.1. I also noticed that the URL is changed from /de/... to e.g. /en/... when not logged in. When logged in the URL is changed to /web/... (not including language information). Do you also noticed this behavior?